# Combine lists row-wise (Python)

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have 3 different lists

```
col1 = ['2006-03-28','2006-04-05','2006-04-06']
col2 = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'IBM']
col3 = [1000, 1000, 500]
```

What is the most efficient way to combine those lists in another list like this:

```
col = [('2006-03-28', 'IBM', 1000),
       ('2006-04-05', 'MSFT', 1000),
       ('2006-04-06', 'IBM', 500)]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> col1 = ['2006-03-28','2006-04-05','2006-04-06']
>>> col2 = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'IBM']
>>> col3 = [1000, 1000, 500]
>>> list(zip(col1, col2, col3))
[('2006-03-28', 'IBM', 1000), ('2006-04-05', 'MSFT', 1000), ('2006-04-06', 'IBM', 500)]
```

If your columns are already in one list you can just use `zip(*cols)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your superfast response.

Answer (score 3):

The code is as follows:
Python 3.x

```
>>> col1 = ['2006-03-28','2006-04-05','2006-04-06']
>>> col2 = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'IBM']
>>> col3 = [1000, 1000, 500]

>>> col = list(zip(col1 ,col2 ,col3 ))

>>> print(str(col))

[('2006-03-28', 'IBM', 1000),
 ('2006-04-05', 'MSFT', 1000),
 ('2006-04-06', 'IBM', 500)]
```

Just the zip() syntax by it self works for Python 2.x. 
Use the above code to combine lists as row wise (or as spread sheet columns)  in Python 3.x.